# Batch/Powershell: if files have the same compound words of folders, move them to the folder that have the same string

Tags: powershell, batch-file

I have some folders like

```
Computer Idea
confidenze fatali
Casa Naturale sette
```

and files like

```
2021-09-01 computer idea.rar
into confidenze fatali.pdf
casa naturale sette 454.jpg
```

I try to move in this way

```
Computer Idea
     |
     |---> 2021-09-01 computer idea.rar

confidenze fatali
     |
     |---> into confidenze fatali.pdf

Casa Naturale sette
     |
     |---> casa naturale sette 454.jpg
```

For example, composed word `computer idea` is found for both `2021-09-01 computer idea.rar` file and `Computer Idea` folder (in this situation we have same 2 adjacent words).
 Delimitator for composed word is simply an empty space. 
I try to use this batch script but doesn't work, I ask also for a powershell solution so I add that tag in question.

```
@Echo off
Pushd %1
For /d %%A in (*) do For /f "delims=" %%B in (
  'Dir /B "*%%~nxA*" 2^>Nul '
) do If "%%~nxA" NEQ "%%~nxB" Move "%%~fB" "%%~fA\" 2>&1>>Nul
Popd
```

Comment: Where are the files and folders located? same directory?

Comment: yes. are located in same directory

Comment: What about using the single command line `@if not "%~1" == "" for /D %%I in ("%~1\*") do @move "%%~dpI\*%%~nxI*" "%%I\" >nul 2>nul` in a batch file? The redirection `>nul` can be removed to see which files are moved for each directory. The redirection`2>nul` should be kept to suppress the error message output on no file found to move for the current directory. You might want to use additionally the __MOVE__ option `/Y` to overwrite in target folder a file with same name without prompt. Please note that if a file in target folder has read-only attribute set, the prompt is done nevertheless.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

With PowerShell you do:

```
$rootFolder = 'D:\Test'
# get a list of folders inside the root folder
$subFolders = Get-ChildItem -Path $rootFolder -Directory
# next loop through the folders and find files that match their names
foreach ($folder in $subFolders) {
    # use the foldername as filter, surrounded with wildcard characters (*)
    Get-ChildItem -Path $rootFolder -Filter "*$($folder.Name)*" -File | Move-Item -Destination $folder.FullName -WhatIf
}
```

The `-WhatIf` switch is a safety switch which will only **show on screen** what files *would be moved* without actually moving anything. If you find that info is correct, remove the `-WhatIf` switch from the code and run again.

Comment: mm.. ok, thanks, is possible to fix this problem ? For example if I have these folders `Computer Idea` and `Computer Idea Max` and files like `01 computer idea.rar` and `01 computer idea max.rar` then I see that folder `Computer Idea Max` is empty but this shouldn't happen

Comment: @JackRock append `| Sort-Object {$_.Name.Length} -Descending` to the `$subFolders = ...` line

Comment: Um - no. I thought that would work, too - but it only works for directorynames that *start* with the same string - not if they *end* with or *contain* the same string. The examples provided by OP all start with the same string. Consider directorynames `substring` and `no substring` - reverse sorting will process `substring` first, then `no substring`.

Comment: @Magoo No the reverse sorting makes longer, but simular directorynames be processed first. Because the comparison uses wildcards (`*directory name*`), the comparison is always `contains`, so it doesn't matter if the name is found at the beginning, the end or somewhere in the middle of the file name. And No again, the examples provided by the OP do **not** _all start with the same string_

Comment: Yes, you're right about the order - I skipped the `length`. But I suppose I'd have to be more precise - the examples provided by the OP that are of concern ("Computer Idea" and "Computer Idea Max") where one is a substring of the other start with the same string

Comment: @Magoo Ah that examples. Yes, that is where the reverse sorting on the foldername's length comes in. Now files with 'Computer Idea Max' in their name will be moved to folder 'Computer Idea Max' first, then the files with 'Computer Idea' to the 'Computer Idea' folder etc. I agree these names are quite ambiguous, but that's the way it is..

Answer (score 0):

```
For /d %%A in (*) do Move "*%%A*" "%%A\" 2>&1>>Nul
```

Should work - Try it on a test directory first.

---

Given further information that some target directory names may be substrings of others...

```
@ECHO OFF
SETLOCAL ENABLEDELAYEDEXPANSION 
rem The following setting for the source directory is a name
rem that I use for testing and deliberately include names which include spaces to make sure
rem that the process works using such names. These will need to be changed to suit your situation.

SET "sourcedir=u:\your files"

PUSHD "%sourcedir%"
:: remove variables starting #
FOR  /F "delims==" %%b In ('set # 2^>Nul') DO SET "%%b="

FOR /f "tokens=1*delims=:" %%b IN ('dir /b /ad ^|findstr /n .') DO SET "#%%b=%%c"&SET /a count=%%b
:: find a directory that is not a substring of another & process it
:reselect
FOR /L %%b IN (1,1,%count%) DO IF DEFINED #%%b (
 SET "targetstring=!#%%b!"
 FOR /L %%c IN (%%b,1,%count%) DO IF %%b neq %%c IF DEFINED #%%c (FOR %%e IN ("!#%%b!") DO IF /i "!#%%c:%%~e=!" neq "!#%%c!" SET "targetstring=")
 IF DEFINED targetstring (
  SET "#%%b="
  FOR /f "delims=" %%c IN ('dir /b /a-d "*!targetstring!*" 2^>nul') do Move "%%c" "!targetstring!\" 
  GOTO reselect
 )
)

POPD
```

First, find the directorynames and store them in variable `#1..#whatever` by submitting them to `findstr /n` which prefixes each with `serial:`

Next, repeated scan the array of `#n` variables, using `targetstring` as a store of the string being examined. Compare it to each other string in the array and if it's a substring of another, clear `targetstring` so if `targetstring` survives, clear the `#variable` that has this value, process the value and start over.

Repeat until all #variables have been processed - which means they are all deleted from the environment.

Comment: Thank you but if I have I have these folders `Computer Idea` and `Computer Idea Max` and files like `01 computer idea.rar` and `01 computer idea max.rar` then I see that folder `Computer Idea Max` is empty but this shouldn't happen

Answer (score 0):

I'm 99.9% sure there is a better way of doing this, but here's my take:

```
Get-ChildItem -Path "C:\Path" | Sort-Object -Property "Mode" |
    ForEach-Object -Begin {
        $files = @{}
    } -Process {
        if (-not $_.PSIsContainer) {
            $files.Add($_.Name,$_.FullName) | Out-Null
        }
        else {
            $folder = $_
            $files.GetEnumerator() | ForEach-Object -Process {
                if ($_.Key -match $folder.Name) {
                    Move-Item -Path $_.Value -Destination $folder.FullName -WhatIf
                }
            }
        }
    }
```

Since they are all located in the same directory, you can filter out which one is a file and which one is a folder by sending the files to a hashtable first; *this is why we used `Sort-Object` to organize by filetype listing files at the top*. With the files being processed first in our `if` statement, we know our else block (*really not needed*) will contain just folders. Finally, we can enumerate our hashtable in order to match file names to folder names. All that's left to do is move the files to their corresponding folder.

- *Remove the `-WhatIf` common parameter when you've determined the results displayed are what you're after to perform the actual move.*

Comment: mm.. ok, thanks, is possible to fix this problem ? For example if I have these folders `Computer Idea` and `Computer Idea Max` and files like `01 computer idea.rar` and `01 computer idea max.rar` then I see that folder `Computer Idea Max` is empty but this shouldn't happen

Comment: Sorry, busy at work. Theo beat me to it: `Sort-Object -Property "Mode",{$_.Name.Length}` is what you're after.